# insert multiple row in db using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple data in db. I can insert data from consecutive values if the checkbox is checked successively. If i check checkboxes inbetween it will not insert the data. Help me if you can understand the code. Sorry if my english and my code was bad. Help needed

code looks like

```
<?
                $j=10;
                for($i=1; $i<= $j; $i++) {
                  ?>
                  <script>
                    $(function() {
                    $("#date<? echo $i; ?>").datepicker({
                    //showOn: both - datepicker will appear clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
                    //showOn: button - datepicker will appear only on clicking the calendar icon
                    showOn: 'button',
                    buttonImage: 'dlcalendar_2.gif',
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showAnim: 'slideToggle',
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                    });
                    });
                  </script>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="1">
                    Day <?echo $i; ?>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="date[]" id="date<? echo $i; ?>"></td>
                    <td><textarea cols=50 rows=2 name="comment[]"></textarea></td>
                    <td colspan=2 align="center">
                        <select name="vas[]" >
                        <option>--choose--</option>
                        <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <?
                }
                ?>
```

insert query.

```
    foreach($_POST['day'] as $key => $day){
    $day2 = $day;
    $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date'][$key]);
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'][$key]);
    $vas = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vas'][$key]);
    $insert = "insert into spinal(day,ddate,comments,vas) values('".$day2."',
    '".$date."','".$comment."','".$vas."')";
    echo $insert;
    mysql_query($insert);
```

if we have like 10 rows, If i select 2 and 7 and 9th rows it has to take the values of only these rows and has to insert all the records from selected rows.

Comment: Your question is unclear and is missing a lot of details, your current code is from a html table and doesn't have anything to do with databases or php.

Comment: @Epodax can you read my code now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `day[]` array contain only the checked check-boxes, on the other hand the other arrays contain also the empty elements, so your code will work only if the values were entered in consecutive fields. To solve this problem you can delete the check-boxes and get their value from the keys of the `date[]` array. You can use something like the following:

```
    foreach ($_POST['date'] as $key => $date) {
      if (!$date) {continue;}
      // get the day value
      $day = $key + 1;
      $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'][$key]);
      $date = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
      // check if vas is choosed
      if ($_POST['vas'][$key] != "--choose--") {
        $vas = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vas'][$key]);
      } else {
        $vas = "";
      }
      $insert = "insert into spinal(day,ddate,comments,vas)    values('".$day2."',
  '".$date."','".$comment."','".$vas."')";
      echo $insert;
      mysql_query($insert);}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: where you been these days! It worked! Thanks @samer Abu Gahgah.

Comment: Can we do this with the checkbox (i.e) with $_POST['day']